# how to make quartz.net load a different sql driver version

Tags: c#, quartz.net

the nuget package of quartz.net is compiled to specifically load sqlite v1.74

the nuget package for sqlite is version 1.80

I know I could recompile the quartz library but I would rather not (and I cant find sqlite 1.74) so I was wondering if there is a way to tell CLR to ignore the version requirement

The library is not a manifest reference, its loaded via Type.GetType

NOte to quartz.net people, just give the library name, not the version and signature, then this problem doesn't arise

Answer (score 1):

simple answer

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.74.0" newVersion="1.0.80.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```